# WCF service error Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, wcf

I have started to face an error with all my WCF communications. I get this exception when I try to add/connect to an IIS deployed WCF service within Visual Studio:

> ```
> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost/f-service/ServiceHost/v1/BillService.svc?singleWsdl'.
> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost/f-service/ServiceHost/v1/BillService.svc?singleWsdl'.
> Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
> ```
>
> http://localhost/f-service/ServiceHost/v1/BillService.svc?singleWsdl. 
>   The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>       The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
>   was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
>       If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

**WCF Service:**

*BillService.svc*

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="DA.Systems.F.ServiceHost.Internal.Implementation.v1.BillService" %>
```

*Web.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

    <configSections>
        ...
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ServiceSoap" />
                <binding name="ServiceSoapTransport">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <services>
            <service name="DA.Systems.Focus.ServiceHost.Internal.Implementation.v1.BillService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://focus.dubaiairports.ae/services/internal/" bindingConfiguration="" contract="DA.Systems.Focus.Service.Contracts.Internal.v1.IBillService" />
                <host>
                    <timeouts closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" />
                </host>
            </service>
            <service name="DA.Systems.Focus.ServiceHost.Internal.Implementation.v1.CustomerService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://focus.dubaiairports.ae/services/internal/" bindingConfiguration="" contract="DA.Systems.Focus.Service.Contracts.Internal.v1.ICustomerService" />
                <host>
                    <timeouts closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" />
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

This service was running just a few days ago. Right now, if I visit the page, I get the base page (note: screenshot of another service suffering saem issue):

[image: Landing page]

But I get no response with the `?wsdl` or `?singleWsdl` links:

[image: Error]

I cannot create a client for the service. Does anyone have any idea(s)? Only Windows 10 Insider Preview updated to the latest and there was no package update.

**Update**

- I have made an observation: This is a local issue. The same source code, if built on a different PC, runs/serves correctly
- Switching to IIS Express also works

Comment: I enabled failed request tracing in IIS and have this request: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AniVX60enXnSu7Y1iIKHFDxpZPcC0Q

Comment: I'm getting a "The semaphore timeout period has expired" error at the very end while the data is there. Any idead?